# Can I send a SMS when I reach a location-XCODE

Tags: xcode, gps, sms

I've read auto sms is not possible, if you send a SMS through an app you need user interaction like pressing a button.

But if my phone shows up at a particular position based on gps and a stored record that has that gps info, would that not be the user interaction I need and the sms just get sent?

From the code I've seen if button pressed run this code and send SMS.

What I'd be doing basically is

If I arrive at this location send SMS. From my view this is not exactly Auto SMS, its sms based on certain variables but without user interaction.

Is this possible, am I making any sense lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you could use one of the SMS services available to send a SMS. If you would like a free solution, you can use the carrier email-sms to send a SMS. You just have to send an email at this point in your code.

Comment: I didnt think of that, but wouldn't i need to know the email address of every number I want to use.  Like 888-888-8888@vzwpix.com  or does the email to SMS understand what i want to do with just the number?

Comment: If you are using email to sms, you would have to have a function that translates numbers into number@carrier_email format(which is not 100% foolproof, as people may switch carriers). But if you are using sms service, you won't have to bother about that.

Comment: Ok I will check out both of those ideas. Thanks for the info